# Pjsip 2.7 Build target arm64-v8a error of recipe for target '../bin/pjmedia-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi' failed

Tags: android, sip, android-mediacodec, pjsip

I am getting following error on compilation of PJSIP 2.7 for architecture arm64-v8a. If any have idea about in which file it getting or how to resolve then please share.

```
/pjproject-2.7.2/third_party/lib/libsrtp-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a(crypto_kernel.o): In function `srtp_crypto_kernel_init':
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x22c): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_128'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x230): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_128'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x240): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_128'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x244): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_128'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x29c): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_256'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x2a0): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_256'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x2b0): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_256'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x2b4): undefined reference to `srtp_aes_icm_256'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x314): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_aes_icm'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x318): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_aes_icm'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x34c): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_aes_icm'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x350): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_aes_icm'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x3cc): undefined reference to `srtp_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x3d0): undefined reference to `srtp_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x3e0): undefined reference to `srtp_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x3e4): undefined reference to `srtp_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x44c): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x450): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x488): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_hmac'
../../srtp/crypto/kernel/crypto_kernel.c:(.text.srtp_crypto_kernel_init+0x48c): undefined reference to `srtp_mod_hmac'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
/pjproject-2.7.2/build/rules.mak:124: recipe for target '../bin/pjmedia-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjmedia-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/pjproject-2.7.2/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:243: recipe for target 'pjmedia-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi' failed
make[1]: *** [pjmedia-test-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/pjproject-2.7.2/pjmedia/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: did you linked openssl with pjsip library?